# Old switch tripping breaker after a different one was replaced

Tags: electrical

So my electrical is bad and I knew that before buying my house just a few months ago. I just replace a double switch which works fine on both switches. Now, a different switch that turns 2 outlets on and off is tripping 2 different breakers. I did not touch that switch and it was always on before.

Also I want to note there are a lot of overloaded breakers because of an obnoxious amount of outlets in the house.

If I remove some of the outlets we don’t and will never use from the circuit does anyone think it will prevent this old switch from tripping?

Also, it still trips if it is the only thing on.

I’m kind of throwing a lot out there but I am just trying to find my fastest course of action for now before I gut a lot of the electrical latter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Outlets don't cause overloads.  People plugging too many things into outlets cause overloads.  Map which outlets are on which breakers, give each circuit a name like Thor or Hulk, and pay attention to what you're plugging into them.  Don't plug 2 heaters into Thor and none into Hulk and be surprised when Thor trips...

Comment: Does the breaker which trips have a TEST button on it?

Comment: In addition to Harper's comments (which are 100% correct), lots of extra outlets mean lots of extra chances for bad connections - backstabs, loose wires/screws (especially if they have 2 wires per screw instead of 1), wires connected to the wrong places, etc. You need to, in general, check things out one circuit breaker at a time to identify what connects to each breaker and *then* carefully examine each outlet, switch, etc. on the "problem" circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a switch that is tripping two breakers. Then chances are somewhere in your circuitry you have caused a phase to phase short. Re-examine the switch you replaced and see if you can find where you have crossed the phases. It wouldn't hurt to have a voltmeter with you so you can measure any wires where you are reading 240V between conductors. Or by turning your tripped breakers on and off you can see which conductors are crossing over.

Even if it's not at your switch, it's really just a matter of tracing out each tripped circuit and finding where they are intersecting. It's also very possible that the short is connected through a neutral.

Good luck

Also see Harpers comment on devices.

Comment: The breaker does not have a test button. But I will check out the switch when I get home and make sure nothing is crossed. Thank you all for the replies.